# Loading GET request data into a DataTable (switching from local JSON to axios.get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, axios

I used to have a local JSON file that loaded data into a DataTable.

I'm in the process of switching to axios and urls instead---axios.get is working in other areas of my project.

The area of my project that I'm working on now, however, uses a DataTable which receives data in a particular way (see code below). I've formatted my code to try to get it working with DT's format, but **I haven't had any luck.** I can tell in my console that I'm accessing the JS file and the function, but I can't get DataTables to load my data at all.

I've enclosed code snippets below and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vjp5ohz/) that shows ***what used to work***, when I was just using a local JSON file.

Any thoughts? I like DT and its features, but it has been a pain to work with at times.

#### adm.js snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

var moment = require('moment');

export default class {
    constructor() {

    }

loadAdmData(response) {
        let admText = $.each(response, function(idx, val) {
            console.log("loadAdmData is being reached") // --- working
            return {
                "Ct": val.Ct,
                "Status": val.AdmStatus,
                "Classification": val.Classification
            }
        }).filter(x => x.p_h_v == "") // if p_h_v is empty, don't render it to table

    if (!admText.length) $("#adm-tab").hide();

    $('#adm-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "Ct" },
            { data: "Status" },
            { data: "Classification" }
        ],
        data: admText, // ----- this is where the data comes in
        responsive: true
    });

    }
}
```

#### [index.js](https://jsfiddle.net/soum93gq/):

I didn't want to have it written out here so I created a Fiddle.

#### XML snippet (what I'm trying to get):

```
<feed xmlns="[redacted]" xml:base="[redacted]">
<id>[redacted]</id>
<title />
<updated>2019-02-27T14:45:58Z</updated>
<entry m:etag=""8"">
<id>[redacted] />
<link rel="edit" href="[redacted]" />
<title />
<updated>2019-02-27T14:45:58Z</updated>
<author>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:AdmStatus>Active</d:AdmStatus>
<d:Ct m:type="SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue">
<d:Classification>[redacted]</d:Classification>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

#### JSON snippet (local file that I used to get)

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "admstatus": "Active",
        "classification": "[redacted]",
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some issue in this part of code

```
then(axios.spread((adm) => {

    let admissData = adm.data.d.results;
    ///
    let aComp = new admComponent(admData);
        aComp.loadAdmData(admData);

}))
```

Try to debug these:

1. What is `admData` here.
2. Print admissData to console
3. Is admissData JSON format same as what works for local Data

Edit 1:

1. If key values are different then maybe you have issue while reading Data here

   ```
           return {
               "Ct": val.Ct,
               "Status": val.AdmStatus,
               "Classification": val.Classification
           }
   ```
2. Also print `admText` to see if Json is formed correctly
3. Can you add both JSON in question might help in debugging

Comment: 1. `admData` is `adm.data.d.results` which accesses the JSON nodes. There was a typo in the JSFiddle link (called `admissData`) but I just fixed it. 2. In the process of doing so now. 3. The format's slightly different---in the local file the keys were named slightly differently (all lowercase) while admData (url) starts with a capital letter.

Comment: Update for 2. I am getting `[object Array]` in the console and opening up each one shows the values that I requested (Ct, Classification, etc).

Comment: I just added the data I'm trying to fetch and the original JSON into my question body.

Comment: Other data that I successfully fetched was also in XML---and was successfully fetched with `x.data.d.results` (that I got from the original JSON format).